# Transistor as switch with solar panel charging

Tags: transistors, solar-cell, charging

I'm designing a circuit that charges a battery with solar power. Im using the TP4056 for this.
My question is the following. I want to use a transistor as switch to cut off the power if the battery is fully charged. (to prevent overcharge). And to drain the battery. (for demo purposes)

The transistor is controlled by an arduino pin.

**I have the following schematic:**

[image]

The solar panel is 5.5V and 170mAh.

1. Am I correct that there is **no current** flowing between the panel and the charger ?
2. **How** do I determine what the exact transistor should be if I want to interrupt the circuit. (5.5V before transistor, 5.5V after transistor) ?
3. **Is this even necessary**. Does the TP4065 automatically shuts off ?

Many Thanks in advance !

Comment: why don't you use the CE pin on the TP4056?

Comment: I do not have  access to it. The tp4065 is integrated in this :

https://5.imimg.com/data5/SE/CK/MY-5015976/tp4056-battery-charging-module-500x500.jpg

Comment: TP4056 cuts off power when battery is fully charged.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický And will the TP keep the battery charged or does the battery need to drop below a certain voltage ?

Comment: TP will keep the battery at almost full level.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I don't want that behaviour. It is for a demo and I want to drain the battery so I can analyze the charge process. Thats why I want a transistor so the battery can drop in voltage

Comment: I would use a P-chan Mosfet with low Rdson instead. And remember if you are going to do some precise measurement on battery this board has low side Mosfets build in so you will measure the voltage on this Mosfets also.

Comment: If arduino shares GND with OUT- pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a High Side 1A switch that can handle this, with a 0V input enable.

[image]

Any resistor will do for < 200mA but needs 10mA for low Vce(sat) on the PNP and 1 Ohm on the Pch FFET

Comment: When I lookup the TIP42C I see that it has a voltage of 100V although the circuit is only 5.5V. Whats the reason behind that ?

Comment: Any PNP will do with decent Beta

Comment: Any PNP will do because there is no current or ?

Comment: The base R draws current and the Vce replaces a fixed resistor which the datasheet recommended https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/motorola/2N2907/12094713